# How to pass a variable to a model in Yii2?

Tags: yii, model, yii2

I have created a `beforeSave()` method in one of my models to update field `client_id` with the client id of the requesting user (`$user->client_id`). However the model doesn't know who the current user is.

I could use `Yii::$app->user->id` but I think this is bad practice and think there must be a better way. Of course I could pass the `client_id` as a hidden field in the form but this would be a security issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need `Yii::$app->user-identity->client_id`?

Comment: I would use Yii::$app->user->id inside beforeSave(). I don't see problem doing it.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for BlameableBevahior (suggested by one of the answers below), you will see it uses Yii::$app->user->id by default. So Yii sanctions it's use, while you feel it is bad practice. So please unblock that view.

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli: pretty much this line: `should NOT directly access request, session, or any other environmental data. These data should be injected by controllers into models;` in the models guide: `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html`

Comment: @Dubby Sure but that info is not an access request or session data, it is an info of user object. Infant if you check TimestampBehavior, it attaches functions in save handler events.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`BlameableBehavior`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior.html)  of Yii2... `client_id` ..configure it as `createdByAttribute` or `updatedByAttribute`, your choice.